# How to finish this nslog print

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to finish this method for quite some time ,but I am a bit stuck. I am trying to make it where the slog will go 1,2,3,4,beep instead of what it is doing currently 1,2,3,4,5,beep,6. I was wondering how to perform such a method.There is more to my code ,but I will put the essential code up.(p.s.) I did a lot more to try to solve this, so I post basic code for everyone to understand.

```
-(IBAction)setmethod:(id)sender{
   for (int k=1;i<=20;k++){
       NSLog( @"%d",k);                
       if(k % 5 == 0) { NSLog( @"beep");
```

Comment: Shouldn't the i in the for statement be a k?

Comment: Sounds like you're working on [FizzBuzz](https://gist.github.com/3454452).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply move 1st NSLog to the else case:

```
for (int k=1;i<=20;k++){    
    if(k % 5 == 0) { 
       NSLog( @"beep");
    }
    else{
       NSLog( @"%d",k);                
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so i was doing it right, I just needed to adjust it a bit more. Thank you!

Comment: I have a question what if you need to add another one of if(k % 7 == 0), what do I do?

Comment: Instead of `if(k%5==0){} else{}` use `if(k%5==0){} else if(k%7==0){} else{}`.

Comment: @moomoo it really depends on what do you want - to print beep if k divides by 5 or 7, or print something else if k divides by 7 or... you can think of many variations here :)